Pre-processing cow tag images for OCR with EasyOCR
I'm trying to use Optical Character Recognition to extract text from images of cattle tags like .  The tags are yellow with black text, and they may be slightly distorted or rotated.
I'm wondering what the best way to pre-process these images for EasyOCR (or another OCR tool) would be.
Here are some specific questions I have:
What are some good pre-processing techniques for improving the accuracy of OCR on these types of images?
Which OCR engine would be best suited for this task?
Would it be beneficial to train a custom OCR model on a dataset of cattle tag images?
I've done some initial research on image pre-processing for OCR, but I'm not sure which techniques would be most effective for this specific case.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
I tried using EasyOCR and got 1 or 2 images correctly out of 18 but that is not enough.

Your question might be too vague for here. Some suggestions: YOLO might be good for detecting and extracting the tags from images. OCR is tricky because tags are often handwritten and in the images, the text won’t be straight. MIGHT be better training your own algorithm, MNIST could be adapted. Roboflow might have some datasets.

documentation for tesseract: Improving the quality of the output | tessdoc

cow tag on image looks simila to car plates - and there should be many examples for car plates

you can definitely train a network to locate and decode the tags in one go.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
